# Remove spaces in column data without loosing their original data in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
ab= df.MobileNum.str.replace(' ','')
print ab
```

As in the screenshot you can see first four row shows nan which is my 10 digit original number without space and other has spaces .
so i want to show first four row data with this result.

Comment: you need strip (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013734/string-strip-in-python) i think..please post an instance

Comment: have you tried doing this? df.MobileNum.str.strip()

Comment: Please share your sample data file.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove my original data"? Your command keeps the original column in `df`. By "data", do you mean column, row, cell content, string content?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnGsm.png

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this:

```
new = df.MobileNum.str.replace(r"\s+", "")
print(new)
```

Comment: Try this: df['mobile'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' ', ''))